# Haskell triplet returning type

Tags: haskell

I need to return the result of (,,).

```
functionMatchingExp :: String
functionMatchingExp = "ana"
    where
       (_, fHead, _) = (,,) <$> spot (`elem` "\\") <*> getWord <*> spot (`elem` ".")
```

And I get the below output

```
 Couldn't match type ‘Parser’ with ‘(,,) t0 t’
    Expected type: (t0, t, Char)
      Actual type: Parser Char
    Relevant bindings include fHead :: t (bound at Parser.hs:275:12)
    In the second argument of ‘(<$>)’, namely ‘spot (`elem` "\\")’
    In the first argument of ‘(<*>)’, namely
      ‘(,,) <$> spot (`elem` "\\")’
```

What am I doing wrong?Thanks

Comment: A parser is a function that _given some input_, may return a value (a String, in your example). You can't produce a String from the parser unless you feed some input to it. You may be looking instead for a `functionMatichingExp :: Parser String`.

Answer (score 2):

Your where expression would return something of type `Parser (a, b, c)` (I don't know what those type variables would be from your small example), not something of type `(a, b, c)`.  You'd need to run your parser to get a result out.

Comment: The parser looks like this newtype Parser a = P { getParser :: String -> Maybe (a, String) }.

Comment: @CosminMihai then you'd need something like ```p = (,,) <$> spot (`elem` "\\") <*> getWord <*> spot (`elem` ".")``` and `(_, fHead, _) = maybe (undefined, defaultValueForfHead, undefined) fst $ getParser p someInputString`.  You can't just have your parser return values out of no-where, you have to supply it input values and perform your error handling.